# Spring Boot @PreAuthorize expression not working

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security, spring-el

I am trying to restrict saving a certain object (a `Stream`) with an expression in the `StreamRepository`.

My domain model structure is as follows: a `Project` has an owner and a list of members, which are both of the type `Account`, these are linked to Users in the application. A stream belongs to a project.

I have this:

```
   @PreAuthorize("#stream?.project?.owner?.name == authentication?.name")
   Stream save(@Param("stream") Stream stream);
```

That should work, but I also want members of projects (which are the same kind of object as owner) to be able to add streams to a project.

I tried the following:

```
   @PreAuthorize("#stream?.project?.owner?.name == authentication?.name or authentication?.name in #stream?.project?.members?.name")
   Stream save(@Param("stream") Stream stream);
```

But that is throwing the error:  `org.springframework.expression.spel.SpelParseException: EL1041E: After parsing a valid expression, there is still more data in the expression: 'in'`

I also tried:

```
@PreAuthorize("#stream?.project?.owner?.name == authentication?.name or #stream?.project?.members?.name contains authentication?.name")
```

But that leads to the exception: `Caused by: org.springframework.expression.spel.SpelParseException: EL1041E: After parsing a valid expression, there is still more data in the expression: 'contains'`

Then I tried: `@PreAuthorize("#stream?.project?.owner?.name == authentication?.name or #stream?.project?.members?.name.contains(authentication?.name)")` and it's not throwing errors anymore on startup. But now I am getting this runtime error when I try to insert a Stream: `Caused by: org.springframework.expression.spel.SpelEvaluationException: EL1008E: Property or field 'name' cannot be found on object of type 'org.hibernate.collection.internal.PersistentBag' - maybe not public?`

I would hope I don't have to make the 'name' field public in my Account object, but I did make it public just to try and the error is the same.

Comment: Did you configure method security config ? `(prePostEnable=true)` something like this?

Comment: @AtaurRahmanMunna yes I did, note there is actually an exception thrown. I have applied security like this in simpler cases for other objects.